# C++ Strong Random Number Generator - necessary?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, generator

My newest project is the development of a text based RPG and now I need a random number generator, a good one to compute in different situations whether some action can be performed without problems or not. Everyone of us knows, that the basic functions `std::srand` and `std::rand` are simple and easy algorithms to compute pseudo random values. However I want to have real and not pseudo values. Therefore i want to ask, whether it would to much overkill using a better solution than the mentioned one and to stick to the basics; and if not, what would you suggest? How to implement such a "good generator"?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: every random generator that doesn't have access to some magical external, physical device is indeed "pseudo" random. Anyway, since it's just a matter of algorithm decision (and not a design one), why don't you just stick with std::rand and change it in the case it's unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion is to use [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random.html). It has a [number of quite good (and fast) RNGs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators). You don't need a cryptographically secure one, but the ones they offer are better than `rand`.

I'd go with [mt19937](http://Mersenne%20twister) myself. It has a long period and is pretty fast. But Boost.Random has *lots* of these things, for most of your non-cryptographically secure needs.

Comment: Note that most widelyused one (mersenne twister) is also a part of the c++11 standard now (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Extensible_random_number_facility)

Comment: @sehe: Nice one! As Visual Studio has the C++11 standard built-in I could be happy with this if `rand` seems too unsatisfactory! -> `(s)rand` for now should do this and if get the feeling that it might be too unfair i will try to implement statistical overview (as there is no game master who can change the rules if there is the need to :) ).

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Actually, VC2008 implements it as part of TR1.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I am using Visual Studio 2010/2011 with a very new version of Microsofts C++ compiler and nearly everything from tr1 is moved to its respective destination. C++11 should be almost fully supported!

Comment: As much as I like mt19937, but somehow I feel that this isn't addressing the OP's question. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

The real question is... will anyone know the difference between your pseudo and real random numbers? I don't think anyone will. The libraries you find by default are sound enough that your users will never be able to find any patterns.

Comment: +1 pseduo random is good enough most everything outside of cryptography.

Comment: Someone will.  Here is someone exploiting Diablo's RNG: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zikd7A8DoKM

Comment: And if he gets to have so many people who play his game that he has to worry about the problem, then great! I don't think anyone will given his current environment. To prematurely implement an unneeded feature is a big waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are confused about several distinct concepts.

One concept is *unpredictability*: Since a PRGN is based on deterministic algorithms and a single seed value, it is possible to predict the next "random" number based on observations of previous numbers. This is a huge problem in cryptography, so to avoid this, you would pick a "true" random number from some genuine entropy source such as `/dev/random`. However, this is only useful for *one single random number*.

The other concept is that of a *probability distribution*. If you want numbers uniformly distributed over an interval, you need a method to achieve this correctly, or your random events will come out as skewed. This isn't related to unpredictability, and a rather predictable pseudo-RNG may be entirely suitable for producing a statistically correct uniform (or any derived) distribution.

Since your game mechanics will almost surely depend on good statistical properties of the random events, you should focus primarily on picking a good pseudo-RNG, and then seed this from a sufficiently random source (maybe `/dev/random`). True randomness is no good in a game where you need control over the statistical properties of random events.

Comment: Im going to assume that this is either a windows app, or supposed to be cross platform, but i would vote for /dev/random or /dev/urandom (non blocking) for a good seed if its not the case

Comment: @Chris: It all depends, of course. My personal choice for seeding is this: `/dev/urandom` if available, Windows crypto API if on Windows, and if all that fails then `time()`. Note that `urandom` is itself a PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, it depends how you're accessing the random numbers. If you're generating many random numbers one after the other in very quick succession, then chances are you'll want something more complex (e.g. creating a large vector of random values). For a typical RPG game however, the standard RNGs should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since computers are deterministic, **any** random number generator is pseudo random. However, some algorithms are better than others.

For a game, the built in std::rand functions more than enough. The only real applications for more complex random number generators is encryption.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, every random number generator implemented in software is pseudo-random, you would need to rely on some physical phenomena (like radioactive decay) to get guaranteed (by modern physics) randomness. But in most applications (I'm not familiar with your) randomness of computationally simple pseudo-random generators is quite acceptable. There were a number of those facilities added in TR1, no need to reinvent the wheel, just check this article: [Random number generation using C++ TR1](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html)

Comment: Can't get random values with software? Just post a "vi versus emacs" question on SE and count how many seconds it takes to get closed, gets you about three bits of true randomness ;)

Comment: @MSalters - yeah, there are things like politics, religion, stock market, best programming language ... that can be used as RNG, but aren't they all hardware generated?

Answer (score 0):

In linux, `/dev/random` is a good solution.

For **real** random values, you can't use just a program. Software is unable to generate true random values. But true randomness is hardly ever needed.

Could you be more specific what you need the random numbers for?

Comment: Won't `/dev/random` will run empty pretty quickly if the RPG has to generate a fair number of random values?

Comment: *to compute in different situations whether some action can be performed without problems or not* didn't sound to me like something likely to be an issue sizewise. But you're right, of course.

Comment: no it's a (virtual) device, if "it runs empty" it's just refilled by kernel functions.

Comment: OK, but if you drain the entropy pool faster than it refills, reads from `/dev/random` will block.